# can I make such graph in R - bar chart embedded in pie chart

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, pie-chart

I have following data:

```
    I   II  Total 
A   15  25  40
B   5   45  50
C   15  5   20
```

R data input:

```
group <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C")
subgroup <- c("I", "I", "I", "II", "II", "II")
yvar <- c(15, 5, 15, 25, 45, 5)
```

As I was thinking a better way to present it, I came to idea of pie chart (preferably 3D) combined with bar chart (preferably 3D). Here is my rough sketch of my idea where bar chart is embedded into pie chart. Please suggest me if you have any other innovative idea to present such data.

[image]
[image]

Comment: As part of answer below by Carl I have been asked about my motivation to do so. I do understand that pie chart is not good for science but they are well accepted in business meetings and I need to prepare such graph for business meeting. ALSO pie chart can demostrate composition (divid the whole part into classes - which is my intension). Bar chart then sub composition within each class.

Comment: I too would NOT recommend producing a pie-chart, let alone pie-charts with a bar char overlayed. That said, the approach I would take would take to overlay anything with anything else would be to export them as .svg files, and combine them to my pleasing in Inkscape (awesome free SVG editor).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Come on, lets go wild with the pies! I suggest you just go for pie-only solution - who needs bar charts anyway. Just get [plotrix](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotrix/index.html) package. Here is how I would display matrix of 6 numbers in the form of pie charts.

```
plot(1:5,type="n",main="Pie charts are evil",xlab="",ylab="",axes=FALSE)#empty plot
require(plotrix)
main_col <- c("#ff0000","#80ff00","#00ffff")#nice colors
main_pie <- floating.pie(3,3,c(40,50,20), col=main_col,radius=1)#your big pie
#here are your small pies with labels using plotrix functions
small_col <- c("black","white")
small_lab <- c("I","II")
A <- floating.pie(3.8,4.5,c(15,5), col=small_col,radius=0.2)
pie.labels(3.8,4.5,A,small_lab,border=F,radius=0.3,cex=0.8)
B <- floating.pie(1.7,2,c(15,25), col=small_col,radius=0.2)
pie.labels(1.7,2,B,small_lab,border=F,radius=0.3,cex=0.8)
C <- floating.pie(4.3,2,c(5,45), col=small_col,radius=0.2)
pie.labels(4.3,2,C,small_lab,border=F,radius=0.3,cex=0.8)
#and finally very useful legend
legend("right",legend=c("A","B","C"),col=main_col,bty="n",pch=15)
```

[image]

Comment: pie chart are not evil ....a pie a day keeps doctor away ! however two pie a day can keep doctor near...so do not make alot !

Answer (score 11):

I cannot recommend strongly enough that you read some of Edward Tufte's literature on graphs and the display of  quantitative data.   Pie charts are close to the worst possible way to impart information to the user.   Use of "3-D" images (e.g. bars) in charts is considered puerile at best -- it does nothing to improved readability or information flow.

So let me ask: what information (and what conclusions) are you trying to give to your reader?  Why would you want to present the same information twice?

Comment: Please see my comment above, I put that there so that others with same type question can ask me. Indeed if you can suggest me better way, as I mentioned in the question. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I do agree you on basis of science pie chart or 3D charts but they have great value when it comes to business - look fency ! do not scientists make their donors happy ?

Comment: I do agree partly On Carl (and Edward Tufte"s vision of graph) and Ram's argument. I once presented bar chart to my boss but I was force to make pie chart. I think R community hates pie chart and I can not see pie in its mega graphical packages. I think what Carl has presented here is more suitable for comment rather answer. It is can discourage those who want to anwer and clearly to the asking people

Comment: @John, a quick google showed a few hits for pie charts in R. So the community dislikes piecharts, but they are perfectly possible in R.

Comment: @John:  remember the important rule: when someone presents you with (his) version of a problem, ask "What is the problem you are trying to solve?"

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I am sorry, you are right to ask, but my idication was only that "may be" the comment you made is more appropriate as comment under the question not as answer - but this also my subjective opinion

Comment: I don't think the R community "hates" pie charts and there are plenty of ways to generate them using R: see the nice answer using plotrix. It's simply that they are frequently misused and often not an especially good way to visualize data. It's important to know this and to discuss the issue dispassionately and objectively - a valuable role for forums like this one.

Comment: I agree on most part here. Pie chart are good sometime as they are popular among business or non scietific community. I do know how to make pie in R or Excel but my problem is I want build stacked bar on them

Answer (score 8):

> Please suggest me if you have any other innovative idea to present such data

I don't have an innovative idea, but I do have what I think is a better way.

Think about your data. It's divided into groups (A, B, C), each of which also has a subgroup (I, II).  So when you plot the data, you need 2 "visual aids": one of which illustrates the main groups and a second showing the subgroups.

A sensible way to do this is to separate the main groups by position and indicate the subgroups by colour.

So, you can reshape your data into a data frame (df1) which looks like this:

```
  group subgroup yvar
1     A        I   15
2     B        I    5
3     C        I   15
4     A       II   25
5     B       II   45
6     C       II    5
```

And then use ggplot to generate a stacked bar plot:

```
library(ggplot)
ggplot(df1, aes(x = group, y = yvar, fill = subgroup)) + geom_bar()
```

Result:

[image]

Note that ggplot calculates the totals for you.  Look at that, look at your combined 3D bar + pie charts and ask yourself: which one best conveys the key features of the data, at a glance?

Please trust me and the data visualization experts on this forum when we tell you: what matters is clear presentation, not "what business people want."

Comment: Scientifically speaking this is the right answer.  But, if the boss wants a pie chart then the boss wants a pie chart.  Us scientists need to get off our high horses sometimes.

Comment: I'd hope that what the boss wants is good data analysis. Sometimes you have to tell people that they don't really want what they thought they wanted, because you have something better. If that's a "high horse", then fair enough :)

Comment: I think the stacked barchart is better than what the OP wants, however, I have don't really like stacked bar charts either :). The second (blue) category above does not share a common baseline, it is therefore hard to see the development between the groups in that subgroup.

Comment: True, if you are important enough to do that -- sorry I was being rather flippant and not really expressing my thoughts fully.  More generally, it's worth considering that you sometimes need to change the language you use (including style of graphs) depending on your audience.  If people understand pie charts and expect a pie chart well maybe that's just their language.

Comment: I agree with bob that sometimes a pie chart can be effective given a certain audience. However, sometimes using inefficient graphing can obscure the trends in the data,  or even show false trends. The books by tufte contain examples of this. In this situation, good practice should be used instead of showing the boss what he wants.

Comment: It is not boss but one of reviwer in my paper has asked for a pie chart...do I want to risk for not creating pie chart ....

Comment: I'm also not a huge fan of the stacked bar chart. It depends what you want from the data. In this case, given that the questioner summed subgroups I and II, it seemed that they were interested in the relative contributions of I and II to the totals for A, B and C. The stacked bar chart shows that effectively. Of course if you want a common baseline, it's very easy not to stack with ggplot.

Comment: Scietifically, I though about the stacked bar ...but my boss wanted to have pie ...so I had to post this question at this forum. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I agree with some of the other answerers that a piechart may not be the best way of graphing this kind of data. I'd much rather go for a line plot with a line for each of the subcategories.

A quick google for "R create pie charts" lead showed [this link as the first hit](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/pie.html). It shows a plethora of options to create piecharts. A similar google for barcharts lead to [this link](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/r/#barcharts).

In regard to combining the plots, I'd create the plots seperately and combine them using a drawing program such as the gimp or inkscape. This is especially effective when you do not want to create these kinds of plots dozens of times.

Comment: Using a separate program to do a mashup is really going to be to your benefit, I agree.  The only reason not to is for reproducibility.  But it will take you a lot of effort to make your plots not overlap, put your labels in the right place, etc.

Comment: I agree with @alexplanation. Doing this by hand will take some time, but programming it in R will also take quite some time...

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using python/matplotlib?  Equally free and good, and has options for (a) pie chart and (b) overlaying graphs on other graphs, which might do what you want.

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html

Or you could do an exploded pie chart to show subcategories:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/pie_demo.html

Comment: That R does not have any pie chart is nonsense. There are multiple ways to create them.