# Harvey balls in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, visualization, lattice

How to create a chart like the following in R?

[image]

Some toy data would look like this:

```
# Data
data <- rep(c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100),6) 
data <-  matrix(data, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE) 
colnames(data) <- paste0("factor_", seq(3))
rownames(data) <- paste0("observation_", seq(10))


#                factor_1 factor_2 factor_3
# observation_1         0       25       50
# observation_2        75      100        0
# observation_3        25       50       75
# observation_4       100        0       25
# observation_5        50       75      100
# observation_6         0       25       50
# observation_7        75      100        0
# observation_8        25       50       75
# observation_9       100        0       25
# observation_10       50       75      100
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would aim for something with Unicode symbols.

Comment: agreed to @BenBolker.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a quick & dirty solution using base graphics and unicode symbols:

```
library(extrafont)
# font_import() # ... if you need to
loadfonts()
getPch <- function(x) {
  sapply(x, function(x) {
    switch(as.character(x), 
    "0"=-9675,
    "25"=-9684,
    "50"=-9682,
    "75"=-9685,
    "100"=-9679
  )})
}
par(mar=c(2, 7, 2, 4))
plot(y =rep(1:nrow(data), ncol(data)), 
     x = rep(1:ncol(data), each=nrow(data)), 
     pch = getPch(as.vector(data)), 
     axes = F, xlab = "", ylab = "",
     cex = 3, xlim = c(.5, ncol(data) + .5),
     family = "Arial Unicode MS")
abline(v = 0:ncol(data)+.5)
abline(h = 1:nrow(data) + .5)
mtext(side = 1, at=1:ncol(data), text=colnames(data))
mtext(side = 2, at=1:nrow(data), text=rownames(data), las=2)
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) I was looking around for `pch` values. Where did you find them? Best approach I think.

Comment: @Marcinthebox google search sent me to the right unicodes (https://www.google.de/search?q=unicode+half+circle)

Comment: I guess I didn't look that hard after all: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvey_Balls

Comment: Dumb question: Downloaded `extrafont 0.15` from github, but attempts to "install from local zip archive" (on windows7) fails silently.  What am I missing?

Comment: Used your `getPch()` function here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74035081/10276092

Answer (score 10):

Jeez, I wasted too much time on this ...

It's not perfect - one would need to play with the units of the axes to get it to always produce "circular" circles (as opposed to ovals), but you get the gist:

```
# Data
data <- rep(c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100),6) 
data <-  matrix(data, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE) 
colnames(data) <- paste0("factor_", seq(3))
rownames(data) <- paste0("observation_", seq(10))

#plot
data <- t(data)

par(mar=c(1,8,8,1))
image(x=seq(nrow(data)), y=seq(ncol(data)), z=data, col=NA, axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
axis(3, at=seq(nrow(data)), labels=rownames(data), las=2)
axis(2, at=seq(ncol(data)), labels=colnames(data), las=2)
rad <- 0.25
n <- 100
full.circ <- data.frame(x=cos(seq(0,2*pi,,n))*rad,  y=sin(seq(0,2*pi,,n))*rad)
bottom.circ <- data.frame(x=cos(seq(1*pi,2*pi,,n))*rad,  y=sin(seq(1*pi,2*pi,,n))*rad)
top.circ <- data.frame(x=cos(seq(0,1*pi,,n))*rad,  y=sin(seq(0,1*pi,,n))*rad)
for(i in seq(data)){
    val <- data[i]
    xi <- (i-1) %% nrow(data) +1
    yi <- (i-1) %/% nrow(data) +1
    if(val>=0 & val<25){
        polygon(x=xi+full.circ$x, y=yi+full.circ$y)
    }
    if(val>=25 & val<50){
        polygon(x=xi+full.circ$x, y=yi+full.circ$y)
        polygon(x=xi+bottom.circ$x, y=yi+bottom.circ$y, col=1)
    }
    if(val>=50 & val<75){
        polygon(x=xi+full.circ$x, y=yi+full.circ$y)
        polygon(x=xi+top.circ$x, y=yi+top.circ$y, col=1)
    }       
    if(val>=75 & val<=100){
        polygon(x=xi+full.circ$x, y=yi+full.circ$y, col=1)
    }       
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do exactly what you want in `ggplot2` without a custom set of grobs and a custom geom, but this is a close approximation if you're willing to average out the ink:

```
library(reshape2)    
library(ggplot2)

df <- melt(data)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Var2, y=Var1)) + 
  geom_point(aes(alpha=value), shape=21, fill="black", size=15) +
  geom_point(shape=21, color="black", size=15)
```

[image]

Comment: When posting this question I was thinking about two posts I ran across recently: http://www.quantumforest.com/2012/02/if-you-have-to-use-circles/
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742604/can-i-make-such-graph-in-r-bar-chart-embedded-in-pie-chart, which describe somehow comparable graphs (at least in a very broad sense). I am far from being an expert in ggplot2 or lattice, thus my question on SO.

Comment: @majom, you can definitely do facetted pie charts in `ggplot2` if that is acceptable.

Comment: @Brodie but would the half fill line be horizontal?  I believe it would be vertical without some hacking.

Comment: @TylerRinker, `+ coord_polar(start=pi/2)` will deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @BrodieG above, you can do this in ggplot with a facet_grid pie chart. To do it in quarter-circle order:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  reshape2::melt() %>% 
  mutate(value=if_else(value==0,NA_real_,value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x='',y=value))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="black",fill='black')+
  coord_polar("y", start = 0)+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0),
        strip.text.x = element_text(colour = 'black',angle = 45),
        strip.background.x = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank())+
  facet_grid(Var1~Var2,switch = 'y')+
  xlab('')+
  ylab('')
```

[image: harvey-balls1]

I assume that is what the OP wanted since they included 25 and 75 values but if, as also suggested in the comments you wanted the half-values to be at the bottom rather than the right:

```
data %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric,function(x) ifelse(x==50,25,0)) %>% 
  mutate(flag=T) %>% 
  bind_rows(data %>%
              as.data.frame() %>%  
              rownames_to_column() %>% 
              mutate(flag=F)) %>% 
  reshape2::melt(id.vars=c('rowname','flag')) %>% 
  mutate(value=if_else(value==0,NA_real_,value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x='',y=value))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=flag,color=flag),stat="identity", width=1)+
  coord_polar("y", start = 0)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('black','white'))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('black','white'))+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0),
        strip.text.x = element_text(colour = 'black',angle = 45),
        strip.background.x = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'none')+
  facet_grid(rowname~variable,switch = 'y')+
  xlab('')+
  ylab('')
```

[image: harvey-balls2]

(if anyone knows of a theme adjustment that puts continuous lines between the panels in facet_grid rather than borders around them, please leave a comment)