# strange interaction between text() and intToUtf8()

Tags: r, unicode

After learning about the Unicode values for "Harvey Balls" , [Harvey balls in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225086/harvey-balls-in-r) ,  I tried an alternative plotting approach.  Strange things happen:

```
plot(1:10,t='n')
 text(1,1,c(intToUtf8(c(1,9684))),cex=3)
 text(2,2,c(intToUtf8(c(9684))),cex=3)
 text(3,3,c(intToUtf8(c(9679,9684))),cex=3)
 text(4,4,c(intToUtf8(c(9679))),cex=3)
 text(5,5,c(intToUtf8(c(9685,9684))),cex=3)
 text(6,6,c(intToUtf8(c(9682,9685))),cex=3)
 text(7,7,c(intToUtf8(c(9682,9675))),cex=3)
 text(8,8,c(intToUtf8(c(9682,9682))),cex=3)
```

[image: resulting plot]

I can't figure it out -- sometimes the Unicode values get recognized, and sometimes not; and it seems to depend heavily on the first value in  my concatenation.  The immediate problem is that I can't plot a specific Harvey Ball all by itself, but I'm more worried about the difficulty in getting `text` -- or maybe `intToUtf8` to properly retrieve the desired symbol.

Any ideas?

edit:  R 3.0.2, Windows7.  I'm going to try to reproduce this later on when I can get to an OSX machine.  In the meantime, success/failure stories greatfully accepted.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I ran the code and I see only the balls. I'm not sure what is the desired output, so it is possible that what I see is still wrong, but in a different way. (ok, I'm on R 3.0.2, Ubuntu 12.04LTS - might be the source of the difference)

Comment: @amit I want to see various balls, but if the first number in my collection is `9684` or `9682` or `9685`, I get the default "empty square" drawn instead of a symbol.

Comment: It's worse under OSX -- I only get the empty and filled circles (or dead squares) no matter what order.  Something tells me there's a lot of "what fonts are really truly in the Operating System" going on here.

Comment: You need to know which glyphs are in the particular font definitions on your machine. Very few fonts have the full set of glyphs.

Comment: FWIW the linked SO page's code w/ `extrafont` does work, at least on my OSX platform.

Comment: I get the same results as you, and have run into this before. It's bizarre, maddening, and *has* to qualify as a bug. It's not just a matter of the graphics devices either, as I get similar results in the R gui's command line when I do this: `intToUtf8(c(9679)); intToUtf8(c(9684)); intToUtf8(c(9679, 9684))`. (Although if I paste those results into these comments, the "box" gets appropriately rendered *here* as a quarter-filled circle.

Comment: See also my comments following [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780860/fix-typography-in-axis-labels/14781725#14781725) for a possibly-related Windows UTF-8-handling deficiency.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Thanks for the info.  Maybe the real answer is to switch to RedHat :-) (like my Corporate Overlords would allow that)

Comment: Think it's worth me putting a bounty on this question, or would it be best to submit it as a possible bug to R-core? (And yes, sadly, I also think *NIX is the real answer ;=)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien  I'll do the bug report;  feel free to bounty-ize if you think that'll get us anywhere   ~_*

Comment: For the record, Carl's bug official bug report (thanks) is [here](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15712).